# Tabbed (and enhanced) navigation with Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using .NET 8.0 and the latest Blazor web app template with server side only (no wasm).

I would like to have a page able to render specific components depending on the route parameters taking advantage of the enhanced navigation.

This is the code that I have:

```
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}"
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/{TabName}"

@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab1"
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab2"
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab3"

@attribute [StreamRendering]
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))

<h3>TabGlory</h3>

@if (IsLoaded)
{
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@(GetTabCss("tab1"))" href="/tabglory/f7d06f92-5f95-44f2-9bb8-9e96c5a62290/tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@(GetTabCss("tab2"))" href="/tabglory/f7d06f92-5f95-44f2-9bb8-9e96c5a62290/tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@(GetTabCss("tab3"))" href="/tabglory/f7d06f92-5f95-44f2-9bb8-9e96c5a62290/tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a></li>
  </ul>

  @switch (TabName)
  {
    case "tab1":
      <p>Tab1 selected</p>
      break;
    case "tab2":
      <p>Tab2 selected</p>
      break;
    case "tab3":
      <p>Tab3 selected</p>
      break;
    default:
      <p>Not sure which tab was selected</p>
      break;
  }
}
else
{
  <p>Loading...</p>
}


@code {
  [Parameter] public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public string? TabName { get; set; }

  bool IsLoaded;

  string GetTabCss(string tab) => TabName?.Equals(tab, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link";

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(500);
    IsLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

In the code as is, `TabName` is always null.

Removing / commenting the following 3 lines, the entire page render every single time.

```
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab1"
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab2"
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab3"
```

I want `TabName` to be set AND prevent the entire page from rendering again when I change tabs.

What am I missing?

Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Hello, I do not think that you can prevent rerender with your current approach.  First of If you have servermode enabled anyways, why not use OnClick events for navigation inside component. Routing would be used for navigating into specific tab from outside component. Using @ onclick you can even set your Url in browser using java script. I would just comment 3 lines @pages and do what I written.  If there is any specific reason why you must have done it by routing alone please give more info. I hope you will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This feels hacky, but it works.

```
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}"

@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab1"
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab2"
@page "/tabglory/{Id:guid}/tab3"

@attribute [StreamRendering]
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))

<h3>TabGlory</h3>

@if (IsLoaded)
{
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@GetTabCss("tab1")" href="@GetTabLink("tab1")" @onclick="@TabClick">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@GetTabCss("tab2")" href="@GetTabLink("tab2")" @onclick="@TabClick">Tab2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@GetTabCss("tab3")" href="@GetTabLink("tab3")" @onclick="@TabClick">Tab3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@GetTabCss("tab1")" href="@GetTabLink("tab1")">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@GetTabCss("tab2")" href="@GetTabLink("tab2")">Tab2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="@GetTabCss("tab3")" href="@GetTabLink("tab3")">Tab3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><button class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</button></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="mt-3">
    @switch (GetCurrentTab)
    {
      case "tab1":
        <p>Tab1 selected</p>
        break;
      case "tab2":
        <p>Tab2 selected</p>
        break;
      case "tab3":
        <p>Tab3 selected</p>
        break;
      default:
        <p>Not sure which tab was selected</p>
        break;
    }
  </div>
}
else
{
  <p>Loading...</p>
}

@code {
  [Inject] public NavigationManager? NavigationManager { get; set; }

  [Parameter] public Guid Id { get; set; }

  bool IsLoaded;

  string GetTabCss(string tab) => GetCurrentTab.Equals(tab, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link";
  string GetTabLink(string tab) => $"/tabglory/{Id}/{tab}";
  void TabClick() => StateHasChanged();

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    IsLoaded = true;
  }

  string GetCurrentTab => GetLastUriPart switch
  {
    "tab2" => "tab2",
    "tab3" => "tab3",
    "tab1" => "tab1",
    _ => "tab1",
  };

  string GetLastUriPart => NavigationManager!.Uri.Split("/").Last();
}
```

If anyone happens to find a better solution, please post / comment down below!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**